# jhipster 4 angular material 2 , chat

Tags: websocket, jhipster

I Integrate Angular material 2 with jhipster 4 but elements worked without any css or animation . this is an example when i tape :

```
<md-card _ngcontent-jee-1="" class="app-input-section md2 md-card">    <md-input _ngcontent-jee-1="" placeholder="First name" class="md2 md-input"><div class="md-input-wrapper">
<div class="md-input-table">
    <div class="md-input-prefix"></div>

    <div class="md-input-infix">
        <input class="md-input-element ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="md-input-0-input" spellcheck="false" type="text">

        <label class="md-input-placeholder md-empty md-float" for="md-input-0-input">

            First name
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="md-input-suffix"></div>
</div>

<div class="md-input-underline">
    <span class="md-input-ripple"></span>
</div>

<!--template bindings={}-->
```

it work without color or animation , please help .
And if someone have any tutoriel how to integrate chat onjhipster 4 please help me

Answer (score 1):

Did you include all require modules in shared-lib.module?
Had you **theme**.css/scss?

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    MaterialModule,
...
```